# Map two windows shares to one drive

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I am using two windows shares (lets call them shareA and shareB) on a computer in my network. I manage to map each of these folders as a drive in the windows explorer. But I want to have one single drive from which I can choose one of these shares like a normal folder. How can I do that? Currently, if I would use more than 25 shares, I wouldn't have any more drive letters left, I hope Microsoft thought of that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.

You can however browse directly to shares without actually 'mapping' them to drives. Just browse to `\\servername` and right-click drag the shares to your desktop to create shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you can create shortcuts using the described methods. Unfortunately I need to access the folders using the Microsoft SyncToy, so I need to emulate a real drive or at least a real folder, a shortcut doesn't work. Any hint on this?

Comment: Never used SyncToy, but when it asks you for some location, can you not just pop in \\servername, then browse to where you want?

Comment: @stefan: I believe you can point a symlink to an UNC path; try `mklink /d shareA \\servername\share`

Comment: Symlink works, thanks! However, in the end it's not even needed, I can't select the target computer in the path selection dialog (as I don't see the computer on the network), but I found out the path textbox is editable, I could have sworn it wasn't ;-) So now I just put in sth. like \\server\share :-) Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one can do quite what you want, but how about this for a work around: create symbolic links to the network shares.

So in `C:\somedir` you would have two links, `ShareALink` and `ShareBLink`, pointing to ShareA and ShareB respectively. These should appear as "normal" folders which SyncToy will happily use.

Obviously, by using symbolic links, the limited number of letters available for drives becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Nice idea and btw it works :-)